# Loop through an array of dates and group days by month

Tags: php, arrays, loops, date

With PHP, I'd like to be able to loop through an array of dates and display the days grouped by months.

The end result would look like this:

```
March 24th, 31st
April 7th, 14th, 21st, 28th
```

ETC

Here's the Array.

```
Array ( [0] => 2017-03-24 [1] => 2017-03-31 [2] => 2017-04-07 [3] => 2017-04-14 [4] => 2017-04-21 [5] => 2017-04-28 [6] => 2017-05-05 [7] => 2017-05-12 [8] => 2017-05-19 [9] => 2017-05-26 [10] => 2017-06-02 [11] => 2017-06-09 [12] => 2017-06-16 [13] => 2017-06-23 [14] => 2017-06-30 [15] => 2017-07-07 [16] => 2017-07-14 [17] => 2017-07-21 [18] => 2017-07-28 [19] => 2017-08-04 [20] => 2017-08-11 [21] => 2017-08-18 [22] => 2017-08-25 [23] => 2017-09-01 [24] => 2017-09-08 [25] => 2017-09-15 [26] => 2017-09-22 [27] => 2017-09-29 [28] => 2017-10-06 [29] => 2017-10-13 [30] => 2017-10-20 [31] => 2017-10-27 )
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$dates = array('2017-03-24', '2017-03-24', '2017-04-07', '2017-04-14', '2017-04-21', '2017-04-28');
$months = array();
foreach ($dates as $date_str) {
  $timestamp = strtotime($date_str);
  $month = date('F', $timestamp);
  $date = date('jS', $timestamp);

  if (empty($months[$month])) {
      $months[$month] = array();
  }

  $months[$month][] = $date;
}

foreach ($months as $month => $dates) {
  echo $month . " " . implode(", ", $dates) . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Wow! This works perfectly!!! Thank you so much. I wish I would have asked the 1st time but how would I exclude days prior to today?

Comment: after $timestamp = strtotime();  add:   if ($timestamp < mktime()){continue;}

Comment: `if (empty($months[$month])) {
      $months[$month] = array();
  }` is not necessary in PHP.  You don't need to declare the parent element before pushing a child element if you are using square brace syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Same concept as the already accepted answer, but with `array_` functions and `DateTime` objects.

Group the array by months:

```
$months = array_reduce($dates, function($months, $date) {
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $months[$date->format('F')][] = $date->format('jS');
    return $months;
});
```

Output the days for each month:

```
array_walk($months, function($days, $month) {
    echo "$month ". implode(', ', $days) . '<br>';
});
```